# matlab: change matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, number-formatting, floating-point-precision

I have a code that load cell array and convert them to matrix.
now this matrix shows 4 numbers after floating point for example

```
0   5   15  1   51,9000 3,4000
0   5   15  1   51,9000 3,4000
0   5   15  1   51,9000 3,4000
```

how can I change all af the rows to just show 2 numbers after the floating point ?
please consider that I want to change the matrix not print it in command window !

Comment: ok but no one answer my questino correctly , I'm still having problem with this matrix , for sure if somebody answer my question and his answer works I accept that

Comment: Okay, then I take it back. But it is also a good idea to be more responsive to other users and help them so they can help you... after all they invested their own time into their answers.

Comment: The numbers should all be "doubles" (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision) - so how would you know your number "has just two digits" if not in some output?

Comment: I just noticed that the actual number for one of the cells of matrix is 44.849998474121094 but I just see 44.8500 0.400000005960465 is shown 0.4000

why it adds zero ? why it does not show 0.4 and 44.85 ?

Comment: @melisazand: If your concern is to format the number when displaying them, the answers below already addressed that. If you want to round the numbers to a specific precision, this page explains how: [How can I round a number to any precision I define?](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-4IDMGP/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-4IDMGP)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see it in the command window/editor for debugging purposes, use bank format:

```
format bank;
```

Example:

```
A =[ 51.213123 6.132434]
format bank
disp(A);
```

Will result in :

```
A =    
         51.21          6.13
```

Also, you can use `sprintf`

```
A = [51.900 3.4000];
disp(sprintf('%2.2f ',A));
```

Comment: I used that In my code but it makes all of the matrix 0 ! sprintf only works in command window but when I try to change the matrix it won't work :(

Comment: I tried format bank in command window and it works ! I dont know how to use it in my code !

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [0   5   15  1   51.9000 3.4000
     0   5   15  1   51.9000 3.4000
     0   5   15  1   51.9000 3.4000];

fprintf([repmat('%.2f ',1,size(x,2)) '\n'], x')

0.00 5.00 15.00 1.00 51.90 3.40 
0.00 5.00 15.00 1.00 51.90 3.40 
0.00 5.00 15.00 1.00 51.90 3.40
```

Comment: it made all of my rows 6 ! I dont know why !

Comment: I have a code that load cell array and convert them to matrix. now I want to change the matrix .

Comment: Hmm, but you seem to ask sth different in the question?